# Why does it use 'the other' instead of 'each other' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, pronouns, determiners

> The case came to light when both families filed criminal charges with police accusing *the other* family's son of rape.
>
> The case came to light when both families filed criminal charges with police accusing *each other* family's son of rape.

The first sentence was excerpted from a [news article](https://www.yahoo.com/news/pakistani-council-orders-revenge-rape-16-old-girl-094012520.html). It seems to me that the former sentence imply there could be other family involved whereas the latter one is limited between two families. Why should it use 'the other' rather than 'each other' in that sentence of the news article?

Comment: "News" is a plural noun with no singular form, like _clothes_. We can never say "a news" in English.

Comment: Isn't news an uncountable noun (singular) with a plural form ?

Comment: Your correction is worse than the original! To use _each_ in the sentence, try: _"The case came to light when both families filed criminal charges with police, each accusing the other family's son of rape."_

Comment: The original is awkward; but the use of *both families* as plural subject in effect 'pre-empts' the use of *each*, which takes the families singly.

Comment: "News" is plural in form but singular in construction. It's a _plurale tantum_, like _clothes_. We don't say "a news" any more than we say "a clothes" or "a trousers".

Comment: @StoneyB You don't think my version finessed the issue well?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Ah, I have mixed my contexts: my comment was directed towards the OP, not to your comment. Your version fixes the problem by providing *accuse* with a distinct subject.

Comment: @StoneyB What does 'but the use of both families as plural subject in effect 'pre-empts' the use of each, which takes the families singly'  mean?

Comment: @user239460 You have a 'set' composed of two members. *Both* is plural, referring to all members of the set collectively, while *each* is singular, referring to the  members one-by-one. Consequently, you can't use *both* and *each* to refer to the same set in the same clause. Your original sentence starts by using *both*, so that excludes using *each* in the same clause.

Comment: @StoneyB  thanks. i get it now, English is so logic a language that one word affects the other.

Answer (score 2):

> The case came to light when both families filed criminal charges with police accusing **the other** family's son of rape.

is correct. Using "the other" is limited to "both families" already mentioned. One accuses "the other" without any third party.

If there were a third party, then you would need:

> The case came to light when both families filed criminal charges with police accusing **another** family's son of rape.

The example using *each other*:

> The case came to light when both families filed criminal charges with police accusing **each other family's** son of rape.

is overly wordy and frankly doesn't read well. A more appropriate usage of *each other* might be:

> The case came to light when both families filed criminal charges with police accusing **each other** of lying about what happened.

Basically, don't use *each other* as a modifier.

Comment: thanks. May i ask why can't it be used as modifier?